# SAS %STR function not work

Tags: macros, sas

I am trying to use %STR function to mask % in the string. Code like this:

```
options symbolgen;
%let grp=%str(%C16F%);
%put group is &grp;
```

It doesn't work. Actually when I click the codes follow it, SAS does nothing. Nothing happens.

Do you know the reason? How to fix it?

Thank you for your help!
L.

Answer (score 3):

The `%STR()` needs you to add extra `%` in front of second `%` in your string because otherwise it thinks you are trying use the `%` to escape the right parenthesis. That is why it appears nothing is running. The %LET statement is still waiting to see the end of the `%str()` function call and the terminal `;`.

```
%let grp=%str(%C16F%%);
%put group is &grp;
```

I find it is easier to either use a data step and `%superq()` to make sure the value is quoted.

```
data _null_;
  call symputx('grp','%C16F%');
run;
%let grp=%superq(grp);
```

Or use `%qsysfunc()` to call `dequote()` to remove the physical single quotes and add macro quoting.

```
%let grp=%qsysfunc(dequote('%C16F%'));
```

Comment: You may also want to add that the OP should make sure their session is not in an 'unstable' state when trying your solution.  i.e. restart their SAS session.

Comment: Wouldn't `%nrstr(%C16F%%)` be better than using `%str()`, so that the code does not attempt to invoke a macro named C16F?

Comment: I did try to restart SAS and use %nrstr, both not work. Tom's answer is the answer. Thank you all!

Comment: Using %nrstr() should work, you still need to double the `%` characters, or at least the one that is right before the `)`.  Using %nrstr() instead of %str() should remove the attempts to call a macro named `C16F`.

Comment: Yeah, if put double % at the end, %nrstr() works now. Thank you so much again!